# Запрос mysql по нескольким переменным checkbox

Tags: запрос, post, checkbox, mysql

Добрый день,
поправьте логику, если запрос по нескольким параметрам неверен.
есть форма с множеством чекбоксов, они разделены по категориям: название, цвет, цена.
есть таблица со всеми этими значениями для каждого продукта:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Top"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Sun"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Mic"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Auf"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Seu"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="green"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="cena[]" value="100"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cena[]" value="200"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cena[]" value="300"/>`
```

я выбираю чекбоксы, передаю их $_POSТ.  В случае 1го выбранного параметра все легко проверяем и ставим в запрос

```
if(isset($_POST['cena']){
foreach( $_POST['cena'] as  $cena){
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($cena);

....
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $query='SELECT  * FROM `table` WHERE  `price`>="'.$price.'" AND `price`<="'.   ($price+100).'"  ORDER by `price`';

......

echo $row['name'];
}
}
}
```

все в порядке, нам сортирует как надо. Но если я выбираю по двум или трем запросам, что я делаю неправильно, сортировка по цене идет по каждому названию, а не по всем строкам + мне кажется есть лишние запросы, 
как это сделать правильно?

```
`if(isset($_POST['cena'] && isset($_POST['color']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
   foreach( $_POST['cena'] as  $cena){
   $price = mysql_real_escape_string($cena);
           foreach( $_POST['color'] as  $color){
            $col=$color;
                 foreach( $_POST['name'] as  $name){
                    $nam=$name;
    ....

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $query='SELECT  * FROM table WHERE name="'.$nam.'" AND color="'.$color.'" AND price>="'.$price.'" AND price<="'.($price+100).'"  ORDER by price';
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['price'];
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ксардас пишется вот так **Xardas** :33 Готоман :33

Comment: Но это в буржуйской версии:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['cena'] && isset($_POST['color']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
           ...........................................
           $colorlist =(isset($_REQUEST['color']))?implode($_REQUEST['color'],','):'';
           $colorListFilter = ($colorList!='')?' and color in ('.$colorList.')':'';  
            /* ! $name аналогично делаете $colorListFilter */
            $min = min($_POST['cena']);
            $max=(count($_POST['cena'])==1)?($min+100):(max($_POST['cena']));

           $sql = 'SELECT  * FROM table WHERE  price BETWEEN '.$min.'" 
                   AND "'.$max.'"  '.$colorListFilter.'  ORDER by price';

          $result = $mysqli->query($sql);    
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
         {     
           ............................................
         }
      }
```

Comment: Вау, огромное спасибо, сделал, надо учиться правильному коду,правда, не знаю где. а то городишь городишь:D